# How do you include a multiline number in a Haskell source file?

Tags: haskell, syntax

I would like to paste in a large number constant into my Haskell code, and for readability I would like to have it formatted over several lines instead of one line.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4):

This is a possible approach. I'm not completely sure about it, though. There might be an easier way.

```
largeConstant :: Integer
largeConstant = read $
  "12345" ++
  "12345" ++
  "12345"
```

Alternatively, we could use multiline string literals, even though they are not very commonly used in Haskell.

```
largeConstant :: Integer
largeConstant = read
  "12345\
  \12345\
  \12345"
```

Enabling CPP is also an option, but seems a bit overkill.

```
largeConstant = 12345\
12345\
12345
```

Answer (score 4):

You could make a quasiquoter.  Might even want to upload it to hackage:

```
module X where

import Language.Haskell.TH
import Language.Haskell.TH.Quote
import Data.Char

iQQ :: QuasiQuoter
iQQ = QuasiQuoter {
  quoteExp  = return . LitE . IntegerL . read . filter isDigit,

  quotePat  = \_ -> fail "illegal integer QuasiQuote \
                         \(allowed as expression only, used as a pattern)",
  quoteType = \_ -> fail "illegal integer QuasiQuote \
                         \(allowed as expression only, used as a type)",
  quoteDec  = \_ -> fail "illegal integer QuasiQuote \
                         \(allowed as expression only, used as a declaration)"
  }
```

And the use:

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
import X

value = [iQQ|123
456|]
```

Resulting in:

```
Ok, two modules loaded.
*Main> value
123456
```

Or a larger number:

```
value = [iQQ|
44444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444
45555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555
66666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666
|]
```

And in GHCi:

```
Ok, two modules loaded.
*Main> value
444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555566666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666
```